# Archiving old googlemail labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I use a lot of labels for tagging my email in googlemail, they are really useful and all that but I find that I have a label named say 'Amsterdam' which was for something that is no longer relevant but because labels are listed in alphabetical order it will push down more relevant labels which I have to scroll for.

Is there anyway of effectively archiving these labels whilst still keeping them?

Comment: ...zAmsterdam !

Comment: That is one way I guess! If you want credit post it as an answer. It might be the only way to solve my issue.

Comment: It wasn't really a serious suggestion. (;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite a lot of ways to solve your problem:

- You can hide the label, so you don't have to see it every time: go to Settings > Labels and choose the labels you want to hide.
- One other way would be to use nested labels. You need a root label; you can call it *Old*, for example. Then, rename the *Amsterdam* label to *Old/Amsterdam*. That way, the *Amsterdam* label will become a sublabel for *Old*.
- If all you want is to archive the conversations, search for `label:Amsterdam`, select all the conversations and archive them.

Comment: I don't like the idea of hiding them but the idea of nested labels I think is the answer! Cheers!

Comment: @Toby Glad it solves your problem. I like hiding them; they're still easily accessible (there's a link below all the labels that shows the hidden ones), they're just not in my way.

Comment: I decided to use a combination of solutions 1 and 2. I created a new label called "Archived Labels", set the labels I wanted to archive as sub-labels, and then made "Archived Labels" hidden.